# How to uninstall SQL 2008R2 Reporting Services via the command line?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, windows-server-core

I am running SSRS 2008R2 x64 on a Windows Server Core 2008 R2 instance. I need to fully uninstall the SSRS instance leaving the DB's in tact. I know this is normally done through the Programs and Features control panel applet, however this does not exist on Server Core. Any ideas for uninstalling via command line?

The MSI file for RS is located at D:\x64\setup\sql_rs.msi. I tried running the command "msiexec /uninstall sql_rs.msi", however the installer is either asking for an instance ID to be passed with it or it tells me there are no instances found. Any ideas as to the verbage of the flag that needs to be passed? I already know the instance ID.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

The uninstall can be ran from the command line as well.

```
Setup.exe /Action=Uninstall
```